# Is there a way to save complex HTML (e.g. dynamic google maps) as PDF using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jspdf, html2canvas

So the situation is I built a project where you can draw polygons using google maps. Is there a way to save what's currently on my screen to PDF?

```
<div id="map-canvas"> ... the map is here ... </div>
<div id="map-key"> ... I made a key for the map </div>
```

Let's say that my HTML looks like that above. I want to download what's on my screen as a PDF image.

I tried html2canvas and jsPDF, but these libraries can't seem to display the elements of the google map.

I looked at google's static map API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/) but it doesn't look like I'll be able to draw complex polygons, and then retrieve a PDF version of what's currently on my screen, AND include my map-key in the PDF.

Is there a way to do just take a screen shot programmatically? I don't think I can technically take a screen shot, but is there a way to do something similar here?

Please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots/6678156#6678156
But instead apply it to a different HTML element when saving Google maps?

Comment: Have you had any progress on this issue? I'm facing the same problem